# Email control panel

Tags: email, ubuntu, centos, cpanel

Most of my small customers started to ask me if I can host the websites I'm building for them. Setting up virtual hosts, configuring mysql, DNS, etc is not really a problem. One thing stops me from hosting their websites is the fact that I've never been able to do configure an email server to accept multiple domains with SPF&DKIM. There must be some sort of an evil spirit which stops me from achieving this.

So, I was wondering if anyone knows a piece of opensource (or not, I'm willing to pay a decent license price ) software ( cpanel like but limited to email ) which would allow me to:

- Manage only email related things via a control panel.
- The control panel should let me add multiple domains.
- The control panel should let customers login and manage their mailbox accounts
- The software should offer webmail and SMTP & IMAP/POP3 access.

P.S.: I work mostly with ubuntu but I can handle centos also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question, but I have an alternative : Google Apps.
You can do the web hosting and tell your customers to get a Google Apps account for their email.
Also since Google Apps is no longer free, you can try Google Domains, they do not offer email hosting but they can redirect up to 100 domain email to gmail accounts.

Comment: I use google apps for my own domains but I find it hard to explain to customers why they should pay 5$ / user when there are out there hosting packages for less.

Comment: I know what you mean. But be careful with selling email hosting, I have sold both website hosting and email hosting and people may often doesn't even notice when a website is down for a few minutes, but with email the smallest downtime is noticed and people get very upset very soon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've decided to go with rackspace email hosting. It's 2$ / user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with **CentOS Web panel**. It is a **free** and **open-source** web hosting control panel for CentOS Servers. It provides a powerful web interface through which you can manage your CentOS server and its services. With Centos web panel, you can manage **User accounts, Apache virtual hosts, DNS entries, MySQL databases, Email accounts**, and much more. Apart from it, CentOS web panel is also used to create and manage shared hosting servers.

Below are the steps on how to install CentOS web panel on CentOS Server.

```
1. Preparing Server
Let’s install the required packages for CWP installation:

# yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'
# yum -y install epel-release

2. Server Update
Now we need to update your server to the latest version

# yum -y update

3) Reboot Server
Reboot your server so that all updates can take effect.

# reboot

4) Download and install CentOS Web panel:
# cd /usr/local/src
# wget http://centos-webpanel.com/cwp-latest
# sh cwp-latest
```

Note: The installation process may take 30 - 40 minutes because it needs to compile apache and PHP from source.

Once the installation is completed, a list of credentials will be appeared to access the panel. Make sure to copy or write down the MySQL password and press enter to reboot your server.

Please let me know if you face any error. I will happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - Dharman :) Next time, I will take care of it.